# Landscape navigation bar will not resize when locked

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a navigation controller acting as a container view, that is programmatically loaded as the rootViewController in the appDelegate.

In the container class, I lock the orientation of the screen to landscape using this:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

The app runs in landscape, but the nav bar is still at 44 pixels - the height it should be when in portrait mode. When I flip to the other landscape, it will correctly resize to the smaller 32 pixel version.

I want the app to immediately run with the navbar at the correct 32 pixels. How would I approach this?